# TabbedShowLayout - How to get current selected tab?

Tags: react-admin

How can I get the currently selected tab? Right now I'm getting the current tab by looking at the url (because clicking a tab changes the url) and using regex to see if the url matches the tab that I want.

Answer (score 0):

The current path is in the Redux store, that hopefully gets you away from parsing the url.  The value is here.
`router -> location -> pathname`

Additionally, you could implement a custom saga to do something fancy when the `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action is fired with the next path.